# Excel string to time format

Tags: excel, time

In Excel, what function would I use to convert the string "2012-12-19 12:08 PM PST" in cell A1 to a time format displayed as "13:08" (without using VBA)?

Comment: Is your date/time string always going to be a fixed length string? If so, then you can parse the string and pass it to the TIME function: =TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),1) and then format the time value cell however you want using standard Excel formats.

Comment: Yes, it is always a fixed length, so we can use MID

Comment: =MID(A1,12,8)+0 would do it - format result cell in required time format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a single Excel function that will do what you want, since your time string is a combination of both the date and the time. It is possible to combine functions, as suggested by ASmith, to get the desired result.

he following formula computes a time value that you can then format as a Time using the "13:30" format.

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,SEARCH("M",A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)))
```

The MID(...) portion of the formula extracts the time, which is made up of the character following the first space in the input string, through the "M" in "AM" or "PM". The TIMEVALUE function returns the Excel value of the extracted time string, which then can be formatted.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. I imagine using MID (since A1 is a fixed length) would work a little faster on big data sets, but this works great for my 1500 timestamps. Thanks!
To get simply the date, I assume something similar will work?

Comment: Yes, MID would probably be faster; I used SEARCH because I wasn't sure that the month and day would always be two-digit. For the date, use the SEARCH method if the date is not uniformly 10 characters. If it is uniform, clip off the date with LEFT(A1,10) and then nest the date string in the DATEVALUE function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you always have PST or some other 3 letter timezone at the end then you can get the time and date by simply removing the last 4 characters, i.e.

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)+0`

If you want time or date separately you can use MOD and INT respectively on that, i.e. for time

`=MOD(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),1)`

and for date

`=INT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4))`

In all cases format result cell as time/date as appropriate

Comment: Thanks. The second MOD answer works great. Regarding the first, that displays the time correctly, but for my use, I need to be able to sort or do calculations on the the time and since the entire date and time is still in the field, this is not possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use time `TIME` and then choose your time format.

```
TIME(HOUR(A1), MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1))
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. If I put "=TIME(HOUR(A1), MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1))" in to B1, the result is #VALUE!